# Object.prototypes builtins directly rules

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, eslint

When type checking variables to prevent app from crashing I always use

```
var hasBarProperty = foo.hasOwnProperty("bar");
```

However i recently added a new linting package and its throwing an error on that line saying the following line is better

```
var hasBarProperty = Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(foo, "bar");
```

When I click the error it shows this explanation which I do not fully understand,

https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-prototype-builtins?fbclid=IwAR30-Z0mV40SaIPn0rPNUuyh2J3qJcsb8pE5GhNhTtZUE-sbYfLBcLNTeuM

So why is the second one better than the first?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The rule tells you to use

```
var hasBarProperty = Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(foo, "bar");
```

rather than

```
var hasBarProperty = foo.hasOwnProperty("bar");
```

because if `foo` has **overridden** `hasOwnProperty`, the latter may not be reliable:

```js
var foo = {
  hasOwnProperty: function() {
    return true;
  }
};
console.log(Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(foo, "bar")); // false
console.log(foo.hasOwnProperty("bar"));                        // true
```